# How do I keep UI elements above a UIViewController and its presented ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uivewcontroller

I want to display some UI elements, like a search bar, on top of my app's first VC, and also on top of a second VC that it presents.

My solution for this was to create a ContainerViewController, which calls `addChildViewController(firstViewController)`, and `view.addSubview(firstViewController.view)`. And then `view.addSubview(searchBarView)`, and similar for each of the UI elements.

At some point later, FirstViewController may call `present(secondViewController)`, and ideally that slides up onto screen with my search bar and other elements still appearing on top of both view controllers.

Instead, `secondViewController` is presented on top of ContainerViewController, thus hiding the search bar.

I also want, when a user taps on the search bar, for ContainerViewController to present SearchVC, on top of everything. For that, it's straightforward - `containerVC.present(searchVC)`.

How can I get this hierarchy to work properly?

Comment: Using containerviewcontroller looks a good approach. Just that when u want to present the second controller you can use custom view animation or navigation based transitions that transitions the secondVC as it is same as if you used `present(secondViewController)`.This way the top most UI elements will not hide.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your question is how to present a view controller on top (and within the bounds) of a child view controller which may have a different frame than the bounds of the parent view. That is possible by setting `modalPresentationStyle` property of the view controller you want to present to `.overCurrentContext` and setting `definesPresentationContext` of your child view controller to `true`.

Here's a quick example showing how it would work in practice:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let childViewController = UIViewController()
    childViewController.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    childViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    childViewController.view.frame = view.bounds.insetBy(dx: 60, dy: 60)
    view.addSubview(childViewController.view)
    addChildViewController(childViewController)
    childViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    // Wait a bit...
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 2) {
        let viewControllerToPresent = UIViewController()
        viewControllerToPresent.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // sets to show itself over current context
        viewControllerToPresent.view.backgroundColor = .red

        childViewController.definesPresentationContext = true // defines itself as current context
        childViewController.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```